# Difference between show and list functions

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

What is the difference between a show and a list function and what is the purpose for them?

I'm studying CouchDB right now and reading bunch of different tutorials for CouchDB but this question never was explained carefully. (at least I didn't find it)

Comment: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html should be helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `_show` function is meant to transform a single document, while a `_list` function is meant to transform the results of a view.

Both of them are meant to take the data within your document(s) and transform them into some other format. For example, you can render as HTML, XML or any other format you specify via the `content-type` header. By doing this on the database itself, you can reduce some of the work your application layer needs to perform.

Also, there are ways to use `_list` functions to do additional filtering and transformation to view results, allowing for a lot more flexibility than a typical view.

Comment: That means that I use _list for rendering the complete html file from a moustache template (ul and beyond). Whereas _show is used to transform a single object/document (li and content)?

Comment: Correct, although you are not limited to HTML. :)

Comment: +1. To me, show vs. list is not about complete HTML rendering or not. It is about, are you converting a *document* into HTML, or are you converting a *view* into HTML. Otherwise, they are very similar.